# Cleaning up asyncio all_tasks() at runtime

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have an aiohttp application and a request raises a (fake!) exception:

```
ERROR:aiohttp.server:Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_protocol.py", line 418, in start
    resp = await task
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_app.py", line 458, in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
  File "webservice.py", line 60, in handle_status
    raise ValueError('*******************')
```

I wait ~2 minutes and close the application via CTRL+C.  This raises a `KeyboardInterrupt".  Inside the exception handler, the following code is run.

```
def close_loop(loop):
    """ Gracefully close down the event loop.
    """
    # Log any excepting tasks using the usual logging module.
    tasks = asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop=loop)
    exceptions = [(task, task.exception()) for task in tasks if task.done()]
    exceptions = [(task, err) for task, err in exceptions if err]
    for task, err in exceptions:
        log.error(f'close_loop reports exception:\n\t{task}\n\t{err}')

    # Handle shutdown gracefully by waiting for all tasks to be cancelled.
    log.debug(f'close_loop: gathering tasks: {tasks}')
    tasks = asyncio.gather(*tasks, loop=loop, return_exceptions=True)
    tasks.add_done_callback(lambda task: loop.stop())
    tasks.cancel()

    # Keep the event loop running until it is either destroyed or all
    # tasks have really terminated.
    log.debug('close_loop: wait for cancellation')
    while not tasks.done() and not loop.is_closed():
        loop.run_forever()
```

The exceptions from 2 minutes earlier are then written into the log.  See below.

```
ERROR:mymodule.run:\close_loop reports exception:
    <Task finished coro=<Application._handle() done, defined at C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_app.py:428> exception=ValueError('*******************',)>
    *******************
```

I would prefer to log and tidy up after these exceptions up as the application runs. I don't like the idea of a bunch of these exceptions sitting in memory accumulating until the application exists.

What is best practice for dealing with the excepted tasks hanging around in asyncio?  Is this behaviour defined anywhere?

Comment: It's unclear to me just what you're saying.  What does "I run the below code before cleaning up" mean?  Do you run this as a separate process?  Or do you have a signal handler in your app so that this runs when you CTRL-C ?    What is "cleanup"?  And what log are you talking about, and what exactly do you think causes that entry in the log?  - With all of this, I wonder if maybe you need a try/catch somewhere so that when an exception is thrown, you catch it and clean up after that request in the same way you would have had it succeeded.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your help. I've edited the question to add some clarity.  All the asyncio aspects are running in a single thread.  Yes, I'm catching the CTRL+C in a try catch (KeyboardInterrupt).  Cleanup is going through all the tasks that remain in the loop with `asyncio.Task.all_tasks()` and canceling the tasks that have not yet completed.  The log is my application log.  I can wrap everything with try/catch, but there still may be unhandled exceptions (IOErrors, etc) at any level, and even so, the excepting tasks seem to still hang around inside asyncio, albeit flagged.

Comment: I wish I had more to offer.  You're in really tricky territory.  Dealing with async exceptions and signals is just about the most hairy code you're ever going to deal with.  I haven't done anything with asyncio, so I have no specific experience to help you with.  Good luck figuring this all out.  Maybe with the extra info here, someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: Progress with this? I hope you have seen [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-dev.html#detect-exceptions-never-consumed) from the asyncio documentation. The try/except around `run_until_complete()` works for me to not leave `ValueError` dangling; however, `KeyboardInterrupt` seems to be handled differently and I haven't yet figured out how to catch it.